# Use a definition defined in another class in another file - python

Tags: python-2.7, class

I have a file called `valueType.py`

It contains the following:

```
class SInt8(ValueType):
    # Set _format as big endian signed char( 1 byte )
    _format = '>b'

class UInt8(ValueType): 
    # Set _format as big endian unsigned char( 1 byte )
    _format = '>B'

class SInt16(ValueType):
    # Set _format as big endian signed short( 2 bytes )
    _format = '>h'

class UInt16(ValueType): 
    # Set _format as big endian unsigned short( 2 bytes )
    _format = '>H'

class SInt32(ValueType): 
    # Set _format as big endian signed int( 4 bytes )
    _format = '>i'

class UInt32(ValueType): 
    # Set _format as big endian unsigned int( 4 bytes )
    _format = '>I'

class Real32(ValueType): 
    # Set _format as big endian float( 4 bytes )
    _format = '>f'
```

And I have another file, let's just call it `parser.py`. In `parser.py` I have defined an object called `parameter` this object has an attribute which is referred as `parameter.values`.

`parameter.values` contain raw hex values and i need convert them to decimal format and i'm going to use `struct.unpack(fmt, string)`. 
My question is, how can I use the definition of `_format` in `valueType.py` inside `parser.py`?

`valueType.py` is imported into `parser.py` and they are both within the same directory

Answer (score 0):

simple, just do `X._format` where X is one of your classes or a instance of it

here is a illustrative example

```
>>> class Test(object):
        _format = "test"


>>> Test._format
'test'
>>> t=Test()
>>> t._format
'test'
>>>
```

nothing is really private in python, if what is bothering you is the `_` that is only a gentleman agreement saying *"don't use it outside this class/module"*. But if you know that something is there you can use it.

So in your case that would be for example

```
#parser.py
import valueType
...
x = struct.unpack(valueType.SInt8._format, parameter.values)
```

---

If that is all you would use those classes for, maybe a dictionary is a better option

valueType.py

```
formatType = {
        "SInt8":'>b',
        "UInt8":'>B',
        "SInt16":'>h',
        "UInt16":'>H',
        "SInt32":'>i',
        "UInt32":'>I',
        "Real32":'>f'
    }
```

parser.py

```
from valueType import formatType
...
x = struct.unpack(formatType["SInt8"], parameter.values)
```